# Add Bootstrap Modal before PayPal Express Checkout Button

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal, paypal

I'm trying to use PayPal's express payment system (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/) to add a button to my webpage to handle registration payments and checkouts. I'm trying to figure out, if possible, how to add a bootstrap modal that appears when the checkout button is clicked but before the checkout window appears. My goal is to have this modal contain terms and conditions for registration that a user must agree to before being able to checkout. Below is the code that I'm using for the checkout and modal:

HTML

```
<div id="paypal-button" ></div>

<div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Terms and Conditions for Registration</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h3>Insert terms and conditions here</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <center>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Accept</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Decline</button>
                    </center>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
paypal.Button.render({

    env: 'sandbox', // Specify 'sandbox' for the test environment

    style: {
            size: 'small',
            color: 'blue',
            shape: 'rect'
    },

    /*client: {
        sandbox:    'xxxxxxxxx',
        production: 'xxxxxxxxx'
    },*/

    payment: function() {

        var env    = this.props.env;
        var client = this.props.client;

        $("#basicModal").modal();

        return paypal.rest.payment.create(env, client, {
            transactions: [
                {
                    amount: { total: '1.00', currency: 'USD' }
                }
            ]
        });
    },

    commit: true, // Optional: show a 'Pay Now' button in the checkout flow

    onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

        // Optional: display a confirmation page here

        return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
            // Show a success page to the buyer
        });
    }

}, '#paypal-button');
```